# Spring Boot + WebFlux. How to display a simple index.jsp?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-webflux

Am trying to use spring webflux in a spring boot application to try to display a simple jsp page. For the life of me, am not able to make it work. It's not able to find the "view". It works fine if I use Spring webmvc instead.

Here's the simple setup:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

**Here's the controller:**

```
@Controller
public class WebController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" }, headers = "Accept=text/html", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public Mono<String> index() {
        return Mono.just ("index");
    }
}
```

**application.properties:
(Though I doubt this may not work with webflux)**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**Folder structure:**
Here's the folder structure where **index.jsp** is (I know index.jsp is in lots of places only because I was trying to see where I need to put it to make it work):

[image]

**Finally here's the error I get when I try to load: https://localhost:8443/
(Partial stack)**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'index'. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'index'.
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:278)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ Handler com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.controller.WebController#index() [DispatcherHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:278)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:107)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1755)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:359)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:268)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:135)
```

What do I need to do to show a simple jsp page? Embedded server is Tomcat and deployed as jar file in spring boot.

**Note:** Displaying static files work. So this url works just fine: https://localhost:8443/js/test.js

Comment: JSPs aren't reactive and as such aren't supported by WebFlux. You can use Thymeleaf, Freemarker or Mustache (for example). What you configured in `application.properties` is a `ViewResolver` for Spring MVC **not** for Spring WebFlux.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I feared as well that this may not be supported.