# Kotlin spring boot project not showing JSP page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jsp

I have a spring boot project written in kotlin. The same project when written in Java shows the jsp pages seamlessly. But the kotlin one does not. My code is below. Is there any compatibility issue with kotlin for jsp pages?

When i run my application, I don't see any errors but running on the localhost, the page only shows
"Whitelabel Error Page".

[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAm9z.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<description>Online case record for RHOdisha</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.4.21</kotlin.version>
</properties>


<!--Spring Boot Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dev.miku</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-mysql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Kotlin Dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-kotlin-extensions</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-reactor</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=1206
logging.level.org.springframework.r2dbc=DEBUG

spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:pool:mysql://*ip with db name here*
spring.r2dbc.username= *username*
spring.r2dbc.password= *password*

spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Controller.kt

```
 @RestController
 class ModuleController(
    private val appProperties: AppProperties,
    private val userService: UserService
   ) {
@Autowired
var httpSession: HttpSession? = null

private val logger = Logger.getLogger(this.javaClass)

@GetMapping(RouteURL.WELCOME)
fun onAccessView(mView: Model): String? {
    return if (SessionUtils.getUserType(httpSession) != null) {
        mView.addAttribute("blockName", SessionUtils.getBlockName(httpSession))
        "dashboard"
    } else {
        "redirect:" + RouteURL.HOME
    }
}

@GetMapping(RouteURL.SSOBACK)
fun onSsoBack(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
    return "redirect:" + request.scheme + "://" + appProperties.appBaseURL()
}

@GetMapping(RouteURL.LOGOUT)
fun onLogout(request: HttpServletRequest): String {
    val userId = Conversion.TryCastInteger(SessionUtils.getUserId(httpSession))
    SessionUtils.SessionClear(httpSession)
    return "redirect:" + request.scheme + "://" + appProperties.appBaseURL() + "/user/logout/" + userId
}
   }
```

Comment: Replace RestController with Controller and try again

Comment: @SimonMartinelli already tried. Issue still persists. On a different note, do i have to add both spring starter web and webfux dependencies together?

Comment: I just saw this. So your trying to mix web and webflux?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, i want to build a website that handles database transactions in a reactive manner. I am using "CoroutinesCrudRepository" in my repositories instead of JPArepository.

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli not really. Are those dependencies going to create any conflicts?

Comment: You said you get "Whitelabel Error Page" so there must be something in the log

Comment: @SimonMartinelli fixed now after adding the spring-starter-web dependency. But as i am new to spring boot, i was wondering if adding both of those dependencies in a reactive application would be a good idea ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you how both behave together

Comment: But I found this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62668596/spring-boot-webflux-how-to-display-a-simple-index-jsp

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes, i also got somewhat similar error but adding the spring web dependency fixed it. I think i will have to look elsewhere for reactive support instead of using jsp. Thank you for your time. Have a good day. :)